# How to stop jumping of svg while added zoom in and out feature

Tags: d3.js, svg, tree

hi i just addedd the zoom feature for D3 tree.js but while dragging the svg it's jumping up and down can anyone help me with it and everything is working but only drag gable the svg is not working and i tried few solutions given in google of appending g but still the issue was not resolved can any one help me with it?

[Tree D3.js Without Zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHOfK.png)

[Tree D3.js With Zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/argHI.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
.tooltip {  
    position: absolute;         
    text-align: left;           
      white-space: normal;                  
    padding: 4px;               
    font-size: 14px;        
    background: tan;    
    border: 1px solid gray;     
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
.d3-context-menu {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border-radius: 4px;

    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    min-width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;

    z-index:1200;
}

.d3-context-menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 4px 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    cursor: default;
}

.d3-context-menu ul li {
    padding: 4px 16px;
}

.d3-context-menu ul li:hover {
    background-color: #4677f8;
    color: #fefefe;
}
</style>

<body>
<div></div>
<!-- load the d3.js library --> 
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script >
function tooltip(){
return d3.select("body").append("div")  
    .attr("class", "tooltip")               
    .style("opacity", 0);}


d3.contextMenu = function (menu, openCallback) {

    // create the div element that will hold the context menu
    d3.selectAll('.d3-context-menu').data([1])
        .enter()
        .append('div')
        .attr('class', 'd3-context-menu');

    // close menu
    d3.select('div').on('click.d3-context-menu', function() {
        d3.select('.d3-context-menu').style('display', 'none');
    });

    // this gets executed when a contextmenu event occurs
    return function() { 
        let elm = this;

        d3.selectAll('.d3-context-menu').html('');
        let list = d3.selectAll('.d3-context-menu').append('ul');
        list.selectAll('li').data(menu).enter()
            .append('li')
            .html(function(d) {
                return d.title;
            })
            .on('click', function(d, i) {
                d.action(elm, data, index);
                d3.select('.d3-context-menu').style('display', 'none');
            });

        // the openCallback allows an action to fire before the menu is displayed
        // an example usage would be closing a tooltip
        if (openCallback) openCallback(data, index);

        // display context menu
        d3.select('.d3-context-menu')
            .style('left', (d3.event.pageX - 2) + 'px')
            .style('top', (d3.event.pageY - 2) + 'px')
            .style('display', 'block');

        d3.event.preventDefault();
    };
};</script>
<script>
var menu = [
            {
                title: 'URL',
                action: function(elm, d, i) {
                    console.log('Item #1 clicked!'+d);
                    console.log('The data for this circle is: ' + d);
                }
            },
            {
                title: 'ExPLORE',
                action: function(elm, d, i) {
                    console.log(d);
                    console.log('The data for this circle is: ' + d);
                }
            }
        ]

        var data = [1, 2, 3];
var selected=null;
var treeData =
  {
    "name": "Top Level",
    "children": [
      { 
        "name": "Level 2: A",
        "children": [
          { "name": "Son of A" },
          { "name": "Daughter of A" }
        ]
      },
      { "name": "Level 2: B" }
    ]
  };
//Predefined Box Size 
  let rectNode = {
  width: 120,
  height: 17,
  textMargin: 5
  };
// Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
var margin = {top: 20, right: 90, bottom: 30, left: 90},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("div")

.append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

  svg.call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () { svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform) }));
svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate("
          + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
  ;
var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

// declares a tree layout and assigns the size
var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

// Assigns parent, children, height, depth
root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) { return d.children; });
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

// Collapse after the second level
root.children.forEach(collapse);

update(root);

// Collapse the node and all it's children
function collapse(d) {
  if(d.children) {
    d._children = d.children
    d._children.forEach(collapse)
    d.children = null
  }
}

function update(source) {

  // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
  var treeData = treemap(root);

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
      links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){ d.y = d.depth * 180});

  // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

  // Update the nodes...
  var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
      .data(nodes, function(d) {return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    });
    //.on('click', click);

  // Add Circle for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('r', 0)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
      });
let rectGrpEnter = nodeEnter.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'node-rect-text-grp');
  rectGrpEnter.append('rect')
  .attr('rx', 6)
  .attr('ry', 6)
  .attr('x',-20)
  .attr('y',-20)
  .style('fill', "#337ab7")
  .attr('width',  50)
  .attr('height',50)
  .on('contextmenu', d3.contextMenu(menu));
  // Add labels for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('text')
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
      })
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });

  // UPDATE
  var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

  // Transition to the proper position for the node
  nodeUpdate.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
     });

  // Update the node attributes and style
  nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
    .attr('r', 10)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    })

    .attr('cursor', 'pointer');


  // Remove any exiting nodes
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
      })
      .remove();

  // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
  nodeExit.select('circle')
    .attr('r', 1e-6);

  // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
  nodeExit.select('text')
    .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

  // ****************** links section ***************************

  // Update the links...
  var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr('d', function(d){
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      });

  // UPDATE
  var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

  // Transition back to the parent element position
  linkUpdate.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d){ return diagonal(d, d.parent) });

  // Remove any exiting links
  var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      })
      .remove();

  // Store the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });

  // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
  function diagonal(s, d) {

    path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
            C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
              ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
              ${d.y} ${d.x}`

    return path
  }

  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
      } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
      }
    update(d);
  }

  function contextmenu(d){
  if(d.children){
  alert("Has Children")
  }
  else{
  alert("NO Has Children")
  selected = d;
   update(d);


   var myObj, i, x = "";
myObj = {
  "name":"John",
  "age":30,
  "cars":[  {name: "child1"}, { name: "child2"},  {name: "child3"}]
};

for (i in myObj.cars) {
   var newNodeObj =myObj.cars[i];
   ;
   //Creates new Node
   var newNode = d3.hierarchy(newNodeObj);
   newNode.depth = selected.depth + 1;
   newNode.height = selected.height - 1;
   newNode.parent = selected;

   if(!selected.children){
     selected.children = [];
         selected.data.children = [];
   }
   selected.children.push(newNode);
  }
  update(selected);
  }
  }
}

</script>
</body>
```